# SQL PROBLEM: checking shipments from yesterday, today and tomorrow with exceptions on Monday and Friday

Tags: oracle, exception

is it possible to create a data model in BI publisher (OTM) that looks at the shipments of:

yesterdays date
today date
tomorrow date
With the exception that on Friday instead of looking at tomorrow we look at next Monday and on Monday instead of looking at yesterday we look at last Friday.

The code that we have so far to look at the shipments for yesterday, today and tomorrow is, but we would like to put in the exception. Can anyone help us with this? thanks in advance for the help!!!

```
SELECT 

S.SHIPMENT_GID SHIPMENT

FROM

SHIPMENT S,

SHIPMENT_INVOLVED_PARTY INV

WHERE

S.PERSPECTIVE = 'B'

AND

S.SHIPMENT_GID = INV.SHIPMENT_GID 

AND 

INV.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID = 'BILL-TO' 

AND

INV.INVOLVED_PARTY_CONTACT_GID = 'RSK.50144'

AND

(TRUNC(sysdate)+ 1 = TRUNC(S.START_TIME) OR TRUNC(sysdate) = TRUNC(S.START_TIME) OR TRUNC (sysdate) -1 = TRUNC(S.START_TIME))
```

Comment: Use case to look back a number of days depending on the day of the week

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement to look 5 days ahead if today is Thursday or Friday, and 3 days ahead the other days.
As there are not expected to be any rows the weekend this should always return 3 days if records.

> ```
> with days as(
> --create 31 days for a month
> select sysdate -1 + level AS dt
> from   dual
> connect by level <= 30
> )
> select
>   dt,
>   TO_CHAR( dt, 'D' ) "dayNo",
>   TO_CHAR( dt, 'day' )"dayName"
> from days
> where dt <
> sysdate + 
> case when to_char(sysdate,'D')
>   in ('5','4')then 5
> else 3 end
> ```

> ```
> DT        | dayNo | dayName  
> :-------- | :---- | :--------
> 15-APR-22 | 5     | friday   
> 16-APR-22 | 6     | saturday 
> 17-APR-22 | 7     | sunday   
> 18-APR-22 | 1     | monday   
> 19-APR-22 | 2     | tuesday
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=880f509fecd17a5927e6a4f2a017ba08)*

Comment: Does this meet your need?